# MAAS Apache2 Webserver configuration

Tags: networking, apache2, juju, maas

**TL;DR** Please paste content of `/usr/share/maas/maas-http.conf`

I screwed up configuring my maas-http.conf and now I don't reach the webserver. 
I tried to install letsencrypt certificates for https but that is not a good idea for the internal network, since the local hostsname of the machine differs and it is not included in the LE Certificate.

To restore my original configuration it would be nice, if anyone could just paste the raw content of the `/usr/share/maas/maas-http.conf`, so I can use it on my server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111523/setting-up-ssl-for-maas-2-4-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1112064 It seems to work for me.
Best wishes
Gert Kruger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my maas http configuration file.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24380295/

MAAS version: 2.1.5