# Setting up SSL for MAAS 2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, apache2, maas, ssl

I have installed **apache2**, enabled **ssl**, **rewrite**, **proxy**, and **proxy_http** modules, pasted this [configuration](https://docs.maas.io/2.4/en/installconfig-network-ssl#apache2) to /etc/apache2/conf-available/maas.conf (replaced .crt and .key files with my own pair) and enabled it using`a2enconf maas.conf`.  Now I can login MAAS via ssl, but the dashboard remains empty with a "Connecting... Unable to connect to: wss://192.168.0.11/MAAS/ws" message. What did I miss?

Comment: It worked after I enabled the mod_proxy_wstunnel using the command 'a2enmod proxy_wstunnel'

Comment: Hello,you can convert your comment into an answer and accept it.

Comment: @pa4080 done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modules are needed in order for Apache SSL reverse proxy to work with MAAS (2.4):

- ssl
- rewrite
- proxy
- proxy_http
- proxy_wstunnel

So the command is `sudo a2enmod ssl rewrite proxy proxy_http proxy_wstunnel`

Then restart  Apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Note: Use a .crt file for the **SSLCertificateFile** directive as it may not work properly with .pem in DER format.